# Error in database Migration in yii

Tags: php, yii

I've been trying to do a Database Migration, but I keep getting an error message:

```
Error : setting unknown property: yii\db\Connection::mailer
```

in my main-local I have the code:

```
 'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        ],
```

What should I do?

Comment: Propably missing `]` in `DB` config array. Provide full config, otherwise we can just guessing.

Comment: You probably put mailer inside 'db' component, but mailer is a component itself, it needs to be on the same level as 'db' in components in config, not inside it.